# Как получить максимальное количество запросов в секунду Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Только начинаю делать стресс тесты и не могу понять как мне получить максимальное кол-во запросов в секунду. Кто нибудь может подсказать как правильно создать Thread Group
[image: Вот пример моего]

Answer (score 0):

Начинайте с одного виртуального пользователя и постепенно увеличивайте нагрузку следя за количеством запросов.

Обычно до какого-то момента количество запросов в секунду увеличивается пропорционально количеству пользователей. Но скорее всего при определенной нагрузке количество запросов в секунду перестанет расти из-за растущего времени отклика или таймаутов. Это называется [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) и скорее всего именно это вы и ищете.

Если речь идет о **максимальной** нагрузке которую можно произвести при помощи одного экземпляра JMeter - это будет в районе [65000](https://www.pico.net/kb/what-is-the-highest-tcp-port-number-allowed/) пользователей (скорее всего меньше, вы упретесь в процессор, память или пропускную способность сетевого интерфейса). Если вы достигнете того или другого лимита а тестируемое приложение все еще будет работать как и должно вам придется найти как минимум еще одну машину и [запустить JMeter в режиме кластера](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Есть ли смысл выставлять Ramp-up и Duration? Условно если я начну кидать запросы с 2000 пользователей, установив бесконечный цикл и установив параметр остановки при ошибке это будет правильно?

Comment: Если вы не "выставите" Ramp-up - нагрузка не будет увеличиваться "постепенно" а это означает что вы не сможете сравнить нагрузку и количество запросов в секунду. Если вы не "выставите" Duration - ваш тест никогда не закончится или придется [завершить его вручную](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/shutdown.cmd). Я не знаю будет ли "правильно" запускать сразу 2000 пользователей потому что не знаю какой [вид нагрузочного тестирования](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) вы собираетесь произвести.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Хотел провести стресс тест